# Traefik TLS certificate results in "unknown CA" error in curl, works in browsers

Tags: ssl, curl, https, traefik

I have been given the following files for setting up TLS for a website running on the domain `example.com`:

- `example.com.key` (containing the private key)
- `example.com.cer` (containing one certificate)
- `intermediate_example.com.crt` (containing two certificates)
- `example.com.csr` (containing one certificate request)

I'm using Traefik to host the site, and I've configured Traefik like so in the `dynamic.yml` config:

```yaml
 tls:
   certificates:
    - certFile: "certs/example.com.cer"
      keyFile: "certs/example.com.key"
      stores:
        - default
```

Doing so resulted in a website I could access via Chrome and Firefox, but whenever trying a request with `curl` (or any program using its libraries), I get the following error:

```
➜  ~ curl -v https://test.example.com/
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443...
* Connected to test.example.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

Why is this working in browsers, but not via `curl`?

I have ensured that the `ca-certificates` package is installed on the host, and even when I download the [most recent CA bundle](https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html) and use `curl --cacert cacert.pem …`, it does not work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes While I agree that it's not strictly about programming, this is actually not about curl, but rather about Traefik, which is used a lot by programmers — and there are almost 2,000 questions about Traefik here. Most of them involve some kind of configuration problem. The issue is specifically about how to get these certificates loaded by Traefik correctly, and therefore I would like to keep it here. If at all, it should probably be migrated to [SF] … (have a look at Security's FAQ).

Comment: Hmm, OK, I can get that this is somewhat more like a tooling issue, although the question and your answer shows that this is mainly about server configuration. But lets not quable about that, answered is answered and [so] migration is a nightmare.

Comment: I just want the information to be discoverable for others who have the same issue. I'm really not passionate about where it is (and I agree that there is a topic overlap, migration is … meh).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it does not work is that the intermediate certificate is missing in what Traefik is sending to the client.

The browsers can work around this using the *Authority Information Access* mechanism, and even macOS does this, fetching the missing information out-of-band, thereby allowing you to access the site normally. Some background is [given here](https://akamath32.medium.com/certificate-authority-information-access-aia-7bc56f7257fc).

This is obviously a configuration error on the server. To fix it, at least for Traefik, you can concatenate everything into one `.pem` file. You don't need to add the CSR file here:

```bash
cat example.com.key example.com.cer intermediate_example.com.crt > cert.pem
```

Then, specify the same file twice in Traefik's config:

```yaml
tls:
  certificates:
    - certFile: "certs/cert.pem"
      keyFile: "certs/cert.pem"
      stores:
        - default
```

This is also mentioned in [this discussion](https://community.traefik.io/t/how-to-make-traefik-include-the-full-ca-chain/5423) on the Traefik community board.

Comment: Normally software would use a PKCS#12 / PFX file for this as it is able to store certificate chains + the private key of the leaf / server certificate. This of course assumes that the private key is not stored in a separate (hardware) token... But it might well be that Traefik doesn't support this...

Comment: Unfortunately the [Traefik docs](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/https/tls/) are lacking here, simply telling you that you can specify `cert` and `key` without mentioning what that actually could refer to.

Comment: I am getting this issue with certs I am getting from letsencrypt via traefik.

Comment: I faced same problem, you save my day and night, thanks very much